# #2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query MAMP phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm using MAMP to create a local database in phpMyAdmin,
I created my database and 2 tables(Users and Food)
But when I try to create Favorites y gives me the error

```
#2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

I've found that normally 
Edit → Preferences → SQL Editor → DBMS connection read time out (in seconds): 600
would solve the problem but I don't have those options in MAMP-phpMyAdmin.

This is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE Favorites (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
idFood INT(50) NOT NULL,
nameFood VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES Users(username),
FOREIGN KEY (idFood) REFERENCES Food(id),
FOREIGN KEY (nameFood) REFERENCES Food(name)
);
```